# How to select text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do like autocomplete, when person write something in text box on key up the data show up in div below  the text box,there is ajax involved but I didn't use it here to make it simple, and no I don't want to use jquery autocmplete, what I want after the text show up in my d1"div" to select a text and put in the textbox

```
function call(DIV) 
{
  var str=["app","action","false","true"];          
  $("#d1").html(str);  
}

<html>
  <body>
    <div id="dd">       
      <div><img src="logo.png" style="width:280px;height:160px;" /></div>
      <div><input type="text" id="search_box" size="40" name="se" onkey="up"/></div>
      <div id="d1"></div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To put `d1` html in textbox, you can use:

```
 $('#search_box').val($('#d1').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
var str=["app","action","false","true"];

$.each(str,function(index,item){

$("#d1").append('<li class="items">'+item+'</li>')

})

$(document).on('click','li.items',function(){

$('#search_box').val($(this).text());

})
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4uQj/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/3jEvP/) is jsfiddle link of solution.

This is main logic to to put text in to textbox on click.

```
$("a").click(function(){
       $("#textboxId").val($(this).html())
})
```